# What is Shri hanuman siting on in the given image?

Tags: ramayana, hanuman

[image]

In this image, what is Shri hanuman siting on?

Comment: On his tail. This is pratyaksha evidence :-)

Comment: How did his tail become so long and thick

Comment: Hanuman has shape-shifting powers.  In mahabharata there is a story in which Bhima couldn't move his tail.@darkknight

Comment: That's possibly Angada, if I remember it correctly. Ravana didn't offer him a seat, so he decided to sit like that.. It's higher than the King's (Ravana's) throne too.

Comment: Perhaps you could add details about Hanuman's/Angada's ability to lengthen his tail and the situation at Ravana's court.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above image is not of Hanumanji but of Angada, the son of Vali and has been taken from [Episode 57](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Kht63iFlo4Y&list=PLFPJRCFRDARSfz9y9YPMG_tCTSeYeGNA3&index=57) of Ramanand Sagar’s Ramayan TV series and the incident has been sourced from the **Śrīrāma Pāñcālī by Krittbas Ojha** (Bengali Ramayana).

Shri Rama sends Angada as an ambassador for peace to Ravana’s court just before the war. Angada sees Ravana sitting on a throne (at a height) which is when **Angada rolls his tail as per the image to create a seat** for himself. The incident is described in Krittibas’ Ramayana as:

> बसेछे राबण राजा उच्च सिंहासने। ताहा देखि अंगदेर बड़ दुःख मने। **कुण्डली करिया लेज बसिल** सभाते। पुरन्दर बार येन दिल ऐराबते।
>
> The King Ravana was sitting on a high throne. Seeing him Angada felt upset in his mind. **Angada coiled his tail and sat on it** as if Indra was sitting on Airavata in his court.
> -*(Extract of Verse 53 of Lanka Kanda)*

Comment: So it was not hanuman!? I was thinking its hanuman! But I guess there are stories in which hanuman coils his tail? Or possibly is Angada confused with hanuman?

Comment: @Proxy Angada is confused with Hanuman. Hanumanji was bound by Indrajit’s Nagapash and couldn’t have accomplished such a thing unless released. He could’ve released it but kept it to gauge Ravana etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: @DarkKnight again thanks for accepting :D

Comment: I see... Thank you!